# Find the highest and lowest value for a time frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

`(Not a duplicate question)`

I have the following dataset with `Gmt time` and `Open` value

```
Gmt time, Open
2018-01-01 00:00:00,2.7321
2018-01-01 00:01:00,2.7323
2018-01-01 00:02:00,2.7322
2018-01-01 00:03:00,2.7321
2018-01-01 00:04:00,2.7323
2018-01-01 00:05:00,2.7325
2018-01-01 00:06:00,2.7322
...., ....
2018-12-31 23:59:00,3.1463
```

The `Gmt time` is a `DateTime` with `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` given above.
You can see that each data point is `1 minute` apart.

I want to find the highest `Open` value and the lowest `Open` value for every single day(24hours time frame). Eg: `2018-01-01 00:00:00` to `2018-01-01 23:59:00`

My new `DataFrame` should look like this:

```
Gmt time, Open-high, Open-Low
2018-01-01 ,2.7321, ,2.7321
2018-01-02 ,2.7321, ,2.7321
2018-01-03 ,2.7321, ,2.7321
...., ...., ...., ....
2018-12-31 ,2.7321, ,2.7321
```

Could you please let me know how can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if it is not a dup:

```
df.groupby(df['Gmt time'].dt.floor('D')).Open.agg(['min','max']).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    Gmt time     min     max
0 2018-01-01  2.7321  2.7325
1 2018-12-31  3.1463  3.1463
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I did look for similar solutions, however, I could not find it. Appreciate it.

Comment: How do I change the title to `Open-high` and `Open-low` instead of `min` and `max` ? and what does `reset_index()` do?

Comment: `out_df = out_df.rename(columns={'min':'Open-low', 'max':'Open-high'})`, and `reset_index` turns `Gmt time` from index into a normal column.